# Removing numbers and hyphens from file names recursively

Tags: bash, scripts

I am modifying a simple BASH script to remove numbers and hyphens from the start of my MP3 files. The aim is to rename files such as:

- 11 Song 1.mp3
- 1-1-Song 2.mp3
- 11-1 Song 3.mp3

to:

- Song 1.mp3
- Song 2.mp3
- Song 3.mp3

I have this script which works for all the files in the current directory

```
$ for f in [0-9]*; do mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed 's/^[0-9]*\W*//'`"; done
```

and have modified it to look for all files inside subfolders:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=''

IFS='
'
for f in $(find $dir * -type f) ; do
  mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed 's/^[0-9]*\W*//'`"; 
done
```

The problem is that the `$f` value returns the subfolder and the filename and the `mv` line looks for files beginning with [0-9], therefore any files within a subfolder are not being renamed.

E.g. The file `mp3/1-1 Song 1.mp3` begins `mp3/`, does not start with a numeric so it's not renamed.

Is there a way I can read the directory and file values into separate variables or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find & sed:
  I would ask you to first remove the pipe and sh at the end, and see whether the mv command is getting generated properly, and then you can run the command as such:

```
find $dir -type f | sed 's|\(.*/\)[^A-Z]*\([A-Z].*\)|mv \"&\" \"\1\2\"|' | sh
```

Comment: Nice solution! Note that this slightly changes the question in that it removes everything before the first upper case character in the filename (instead of just digits and hyphens). If that is desirable, you probably at least want to change both `A-Z` instances to `A-Za-z` in case any titles don't contain upper case characters.

Answer (score 2):

Theres no need for a script, there's a one liner for that.

Try this to see what it does (don't worry, this doesn't rename your files yet, see below):

```
find root_audio_path -type f -iname '*mp3' -execdir rename --no-act 's/^\.\/[\d\s\-]+/\.\//' '{}' ';'
```

Remove `--no-act` if it seems to work. This *actually* renames the files.

The `-execdir` option of `find` makes sure that `rename` is executed in the files directory, so the files paths always start  with `./` - for which we look for in `rename`.

`rename` in Ubuntu actually perls rename, so you can use regular expressions there.

Comment: This seems to work but does not move beyond the parent folder, which is where the problem comes in.

Comment: It works for any number of sub folders as well. The output you see is the one of `rename`, which is run in every directory. Because it's working directory is always `./`, that's all you see. However, the files get renamed in all subdirs.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you the path

```
echo "wwww/www/mp3/1-1 Song 1.mp3" | sed 's#\(.*/\)\(.*\)#\1#g'
/wwww/www/mp3/
```

The following will get you the file without the path:

```
echo "wwww/www/mp3/1-1 Song 1.mp3" | sed 's#\(.*/\)##g'
1-1 Song 1.mp3
```

You will need a variable for the path, old and new filenames. You can get the new filename using your code and build a source and target path using these variables. I'd recommend doing a dry-run where you echo the target appending to a file. Then you can check for d